# Login with Facebook in a webView (Android)

Tags: android, ios, facebook, webview

I've been reading that is not possible to login with facebook in a webView embedded in an App.

I have an App with a webView, and it is weird because, when I try to log in, the webView reloads and it doesn't let you access to your profile but if you log out and then try again, it works!

How is this possible? It only works fine after one log out.

(is happening the same behavior with the iOS webView)

Any help is highly appreciated,
Thanks